# Can't connect to MongoDB with Connection String

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, parse-server

I'm trying to migrate an app from parse to my selfhosted server. I want to migrate the mongoDB but something's wrong with my connection String:

```
mongodb://user:pwd@X.X.X.X:27017/dev
```

The version of mongo:

```
db version v3.2.9-rc0
```

When I'm starting the connection I always get the error that the authentication failed. The mongo terminal says:

```
SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed for calimotoDev on dev from client 54.85.236.190 ;
AuthenticationFailed: SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed, storedKey mismatch
```

It seems that the password is wrong, but it's definitely not. When I try to connect my selfhosted parse server to mongoDB with this connection string everything's fine.

Please help me, I'm searching for hours to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: The exception image]

I had the same problem and contacted support@mlab.com and they suggested me to escape my password (xxx-yyy-zzz) (This wasn't my problem though)

So I did this:

```
var url = new MongoUrl(connectionString);
var client = new MongoClient(url);
```

This is c# but should be similar to other languages.

Comment: That's right. Meanwhile I solved that problem too. I had a "+"-character in my password.